# has_and_belongs_to_many and has_many_through on same model

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Is it acceptable to have a `has_and_belongs_to_many:` association as well as a `has_many through:` relationship on models? For instance, I have three models, `Facility`, `Athlete`, and `Event`.

An Athlete has and belongs to many Facilities, and vice versa. I need to allow for Facilities to create Events that belong to both the facility and the athlete. So I have the following.

```
class Athlete < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :age, :email, :facility_id, :name
  has_and_belongs_to_many :facilities
  has_many :events
  has_many :facilities, :through => :events
end

class Facility < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name, :contact_email, :contact_name, :telephone
  has_and_belongs_to_many :athletes
  has_many :events
  has_many :athletes, :through => :events
end

class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :athlete_id, :facility_id, :rfd250, :rfd50, :rfd85
  belongs_to :athlete
  belongs_to :facility
end
```

My hope with this setup is that from Facilities#Show, I can create new Athletes associated with a particular Facility (athletes_facilities table). After which I can display only those athletes associated with the Facility, and create new Events for them.

Is this the wrong way to approach the problem?

Comment: This is possible, but with code above won't work because you have name conflicts. Relationships must have unique names.

Comment: Also from a data model point of view I can't see how this makes sense. If an Athlete who is not a member of a Facility participates in this Facility event that doesn't make him a member of the Facility, does it?

Comment: I probably wasn't clear enough. Taking part in an event, if only once, would make that athlete a member of the particular facility.

Comment: But an athlete could be a member of a facility without taking part in event as well?

Comment: So, what I would do is: set a callback to that if an athlete joins an event and is not a member of a facility, you add him as a member. You'll need to have a lot of join tables to make it work but this is totally possible. I'll write more specific answer later today.

Comment: I promised an answer but didn't have time to think of it. Did you figure it out?